# nodejs cipher ubuntu not working as expected

Tags: macos, node.js, ubuntu, cryptography, encryption

I wrote a data encrypt tool, it works on mac os, but not on ubuntu.
The following code shows the difference.

```
var crypto = require('crypto');

var k = '1234567890123456';
var v = '1234567890123456';
var alg = 'AES-128-CBC';


var buf = new Buffer('Hello world!');
console.log(buf);

var cipher = crypto.createCipheriv(alg, k, v);
var result = cipher.update(buf);
result += cipher.final();
buf = new Buffer(result, 'binary');
console.log(buf);

var decipher = crypto.createDecipheriv(alg, k, v);
decipher.setAutoPadding(auto_padding=false);
result = decipher.update(buf);
result += decipher.final();
buf = new Buffer(result, 'binary');

console.log(buf);
console.log(buf.toString());
```

outputs, on mac:

```
<Buffer 48 65 6c 6c 6f 20 77 6f 72 6c 64 21>
<Buffer 17 0e 2d 73 94 bf d4 24 95 b3 a7 49 73 58 5e 3f>
<Buffer 48 65 6c 6c 6f 20 77 6f 72 6c 64 21 04 04 04 04>
Hello world!
```

ubuntu:

```
<Buffer 48 65 6c 6c 6f 20 77 6f 72 6c 64 21>
<Buffer 17 0e 2d 73 fd fd fd 24 fd fd fd 49 73 58 5e 3f>
<Buffer 05 6d 69 fd fd 1b 49 62 60 39 fd 68 fd fd fd>
mi��Ib`9�h���
```

any idea? thx

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce that in ubuntu. I'm running Ubuntu 12.04, node 0.8 and everything is fine here. What is your system setup?

Comment: I can reproduce it on Debian, both on i386 and x86_64 platforms, using node 0.10.0. It sounds like it might be an out-of-date OpenSSL lib (my machines both aren't really up-to-date).

Comment: Last time I checked crypto API page, it was 3 -Stable but now the page reads Stability: 2 - Unstable. So you should use node 0.8 or wait till they make it stable.

Comment: user568109 thanks! My node version is v0.10.0 and ubuntu12.04. And it works after set crypto.DEFAULT_ENCODING as robertklep motioned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Node 0.10.0 introduced some internal changes to the crypto module which might break existing code.

With the following fix (as suggested by http://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_recent_api_changes) it works on my Debian machine:

```
var crypto = require('crypto');
crypto.DEFAULT_ENCODING = 'binary';
...
```

(thanks to @user568109 for making me read the page!)

The aforementioned page also makes suggestions to permanently fix your code, as setting `crypto.DEFAULT_ENCODING` is considered to be a temporary measure.

Comment: (just checked, the original code also fails with Node 0.10.0 on Mac)